# Unable to invoke SureFire plugin to run a Java Test

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I have created a Java test (i can convert it to Junit as well if required). I want it to invoke when the project build. I added the dependency in the Pom.xml but on building the project, the test is not triggered. I think the Surefire plugin is not invoked in the first place because i can not see any reports in the target folder.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>com.configtests/ConfigTests.java</include>
    </includes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is ConfigTests.java in the same package as your other classes??

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have this kind of structure:

```
 Module 
 -- src
    -- main
       -- java 
          -- com.module
             -- (classes)
    -- test 
       -- java 
          -- com.module
             -- (test classes)
    -- pom.xml
```

Then the plugin syntax looks like this:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.19.1</version>
   <configuration>
       <includes>
           <include>*</include>
       </includes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I assume you want to have `ConfigTests.java` under the package you have named `com.configtests` in the test directory. Should suffice to just do:

```
<include>ConfigTests.java</include>
```

No reason to declare the package prepended. It should find the class properly so long as you have the pom.xml at the top-level and the class under a folder in the same directory accordingly (in the test folder!)

EDIT:
Also, to run the tests as part of your build it should be running the tests auto-magically with: `mvn clean install` or, you can run the tests isolated like `mvn test`. Output in the console will indicate if the tests were run or not.